# Enum characters that contain accent are misconfigured

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

The Code I'm working on is this:

```
$('#@nameof(Model.Destinacao)').append($('<option>', {
    value: @((int)WorkDev.ERP.WApp.Core.Enums.Financeiro.DestinacaoBaixa.ContaBancaria),
    text: '@(WorkDev.ERP.WApp.Core.Enums.Financeiro.DestinacaoBaixa.ContaBancaria.DescricaoEnum())'
}));
```

I'm bringing this information from Enum!

Comment: It would help to actually ask a question. What problem are you having? Can you describe what you're trying to achieve and the problem you encounter ?

Comment: The name of the Display that is not this is ENUM.
The problem is that it brings, but unconfigured.
Example, if the name of the display is "Orçamento", the accent in "ç" returns me "'Or&#xE7;amento'" and not "Orçamento".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the name of the display is "Orçamento", the accent in "ç" returns me "'Orçamento'" and not "Orçamento"

You can try to use following code snippet:

```
text: '@Html.Raw(WorkDev.ERP.WApp.Core.Enums.Financeiro.DestinacaoBaixa.ContaBancaria.DescricaoEnum())'
```

Test Result

[image]